# How to get layers from a specific store of geoserver using python gsconfig?

Tags: geoserver, python-2.7, geoserver-rest-api

I'm using gsconfig python library to acess geoserver rest, my question is how can i get layers from a specific store ?

I'm tried as follow:

```
from geoserver.catalog import Catalog

cat=Catalog("http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest")

layers=cat.get_layers('storename')
```

but it's giving all published layers from geoserver not from that particular store.

Please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try defining the resource first and pulling the layers from it:

```
myResource = cat.get_resources(store='storeName', workspace='workspaceName')
layers = cat.get_layers(myResource)
```